# express res.send return same results for multiple call

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route and I want to execute different functions for each service

```
var planning = require('../tms/planning.js');
router.get('/tms/api/:service', isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {

  if (req.params.service == 'depot_planning') {
    planning.depots(req, function(results) {
      res.send({
        'result': {
          'data': results
        }
      });
    });

  } else if (req.params.service == 'affiche_planning') {
    planning.AffichePlanning(req, function(result) {
      res.send({
        'result': {
          'data': result
        }
      });
    });
  }

});
```

the functions that i call

```
var t = require('./DB2connexion');

var database = t.database;

var depots = function(req, callback) {
  statement = 'SELECT distinct plptrs FROM MTFPLAP';
  database.execute(statement);
  database.on('execute', function(error, results, next) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      callback(results, next);
    }
  });

}
var AffichePlanning = function(req, callback) {

  statement = 'SELECT otnump,otquai,OTHCR,Otnbps from MTFodtp  where  OTDCR=\'' + req.query.datePlanning +
    '\' and ottype=\'CDE\' and OTLP=\'NOR\' order by otquai asc,OTHCR asc';
  console.log(statement);
  database.execute(statement);
  database.on('execute', function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      callback(results, next);
    }
  });

}

module.exports.depots = depots;
module.exports.AffichePlanning = AffichePlanning;
```

When i execute my code I have the same results returned for the two routes, how can i do to have the good result for each call?

Comment: can you provide your request Urls and logs in your console?

Comment: @Abie Urls:                                                                                                         GET /tms/api/affiche_planning?datePlanning=20150911 200 773ms - 55b
GET /tms/api/depot_planning 200 803ms - 55b

Comment: I dont know what you really want !!!!!!!! sorry